# React Redux - Unable to receive updates when an action is dispatched from outside <Provider>

Tags: react-redux, electron, amazon-sqs

I am building an electron app with webpack/typescript template. I have also added react/redux to the stack. In main.js, where we mount a window, I am also creating an sqs (Amazon SQS) consumer. As soon as the consumer receives a message, it dispatches an action via store. The action is get called and the flow gets to the reducer as well. But somehow, the component doesn't get the updates to re-render itself based on the changes in the state. Is it because the consumer (which is started in main.js) is outside the `<Provider>`? Any solution to this?

Comment: how is your app setup? where is `store` defined? Probably you need to have two stores: one for main process and one for renderer and keep them in sync. Take look at this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-redux

Comment: Thanks @pergy, you're right, I need to stores. I am looking into this library - electron-redux